# How to show Activity overlaying on another Activity?

Tags: android, android-activity

I want to show a volume bar (SeekBar) when a speaker button is pressed. Changing the whole Activity just for a SeekBar might not be a good decision.

I think overlaying that SeekBar would be the best solution. (But how?)

How would you solve this problem?

Comment: Why not a custom dialog instead?

Comment: can you write it as an answer? You gave the correct answer at first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should use a custom `Dialog` with a `SeekBar` set as content.

As a side note, remember to get rid of the title requesting the right feature to your window:

```
getDialog().getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use your own customized dialog and automatically dismiss it if the user hasn't touched the screen after a short while, but I would like to ask exactly why you need it.

The reason: not all Android devices even have volume buttons.

If you wish, you can easily just set the volume control to be MEDIA instead of the ringtone volume, so that if the user accesses the volume , it will show the control of the MEDIA . Here's how you do it:

```
setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
```

Comment: "The reason: not all Android devices even have volume buttons.": This is exactly why i want to show a software SeekBar to control the volume level for the currently playing music in my app.

Comment: If the user doesn't have a volume button, the app cannot listen to the event of clicking it. if you wish, you can create a settings page where you can have a seekbar to tune the volume.